# C# Maximize procees doesnt work

Tags: c#, minimize, minesweeper

I'm trying to maximize "Microsoft Minesweeper" (Windows 10) proccess with this code:

```
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;

    IntPtr HWND = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Minesweeper");
    ShowWindow(HWND, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

At first this works, but for some reason after I minimize it, the code doesn't work anymore. I've checked that code on another process (Notepad) and it worked perfectly, even after I minimized the notepad. Yet for some reason, the "Microsoft Minesweeper" doesn't work.

Any idea why it doesn't work after I minimize?

Comment: Does the window text change when Minesweeper is minimized?

Comment: No, by the way ive also tried to get the proccess with: 
Process.GetProcessesByName("minesweeper") and got the same result

Comment: Try using PostMessage() instead.